# Selenium некорректно работает с Firefox

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь выполнить следующий код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
browser.get('http://vk.com')
```

Однако после того, как я начинаю его выполнение, Firefox выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если нажать ОК, то метод browser.get отработает, но некорректно, на экран выведется следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Этой ошибки нет, если запустить Firefox вручную, а не используя Selenium. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: профиль установить не помешало бы.
если не поможет попробуй обнови селениум и файерфокс. только не забудь что  для последних версий селениума нужен geckodriver.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Окружение следующее: - Python 3.5.2 - Selenium 3.0.1 - geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64 (проверьте чтобы был в PATH) - firefox 50.0

Comment: у меня последний ФФ с последним слеениумом уже довольно много времени не работает коректно. То одна проблема, то другая... Давно пофикилось? А то я уже пол года сижу на фф47 и последней двойке селениума

Comment: А ничего, что в коде http в vk.com, а по факту https? Например, если специально не чистить кэш, то после локального http загрузка (и перезагрузка с F5) https из инета выдает предупреждение.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема с профилем фф, а потом с сертификатом.
Для решения проблемы Вам необходимо указать путь к Вашему профилю фф.

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile="C:\\Users\\твой_юзер\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\куча_букв_цифр.default")
self.driver.get('http://vk.com')
```

Дело в том, что когда вы запускаете браузер через селениум, то ФФ должен стартовать с дефолтным профилем, в селениуме, часто возникает неопределенность с каким профилем запустить ФФ (про другие не знаю). Вы должны жестко указать где этот Ваш профиль находиться. Тогда браузер запуститься как будто это Вы его запустили. Дальше у Вас возникла проблема с сертификатами, потому что ФФ запустился с непонятно каким профилем и не знает политики работы с сертификатами (хотя возможны и другие причины). Это мое виденье происходящего у Вас.